# Silverlight client load operation failed for query "Login". [GenericParameterNotValid]

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have one user who gets the following error when trying to login, "Silverlight client load operation failed for query "Login". [GenericParameterNotValid]".  The odd thing is that other users are able to login without issue and I can login using the "problem" account from other machines.

At this point I think it's got to be a client side configuration issue.

My next step is to confirm the Client Side Silverlight Version, but I don't know where to go after that.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install Silverlight Developer runtime on the client to get more details on the error.
2. Try deleting the user's profile.

[This thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/193563/448697.aspx) might help you.

Comment: Looks like deleting NTUSER.DAT was the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving a breadcrumb here.  We had the following error in a Silverlight RIA Services application attempting to login:

Load operation failed for query 'Login'. Error in deserializing body of the request message for the operation 'Login'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).

This was in Server 2003 with IE 8.  Turns out a restart of the browser made the problem go away!  Very frustrating.